# Calling ExecutorService in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, concurrency

I have a normal java application. I want to convert this application to spring boot application. Please tell me how can I call this "method()" in spring boot application at startup.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
    class A{
        public static void main(String arg[]){
            A a = new A();
            a.method();
        }
    public void method(){
        executorService.execute(MyRunnableClass);
        }
```

Comment: When do you want method() to run? At startup?

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/

Comment: yes, I want to call method at startup.

Answer (score 0):

You can run code at startup in spring boot by implementing `ApplicationRunner` interface as below:

```
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;

@Component
public class StartupCodeRunner implements ApplicationRunner {

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments applicationArguments) throws Exception {
        A a = new A();
        a.method();
    }
}
```